# Kotlin JPA Update not working. Why doesn't JPA do dirty check?

Tags: jpa

```
@Transactional
fun test(){
        val people = peopleRepository.findById(id)? peopleRepository.save(peopleEntity)
        people.address = "NY" 
}
```

After executing peopleRepository.findById(id), update works fine.

However, after executing save(), update does not work.

Is save() necessary again?

I thought .. if finish this test function and jpa do dirty check on the value changed through *people.address.*

Because I already did save() above.

Comment: You shouldn't need the save at all; I don't know your setup, but the repository findById method should return a managed instance tied to the context, and that context automatically pick up changes to manage entities when the transaction commits. If it isn't doing that, you don't have transactions setup to maintain a context for the transaction - the entity must be detached.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking at the generated SQL statements. But without flushing, there are none.

this test works as expected. First does an insert and then an update.

```
@Test
void test() {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("Peter");
    person = personRepository.save(person);

    person.setName("Max");

    personRepository.flush();
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer! but flush() not working too..and.. when i use save() again it's working correctly

Comment: I dont want to use save() again. and i think 'use save() again' is not good way!

Comment: You don't have ot use save again. It's just an example that everything works as expected

Comment: Which case is not working? If you get a result of findById?

Comment: when i assign people.address = "NY" to entity, 
The entity's value changes.

but when update it to DB it's not work (Can't update DB Value to "NY")

Comment: val people = peopleRepository.findById(id)? peopleRepository.save(peopleEntity)
 -> "all things work correctly"

Comment: Can't update DB Value to "NY" is this an error message?

Comment: no it is not an error message. test function works correctly. 
There is just no action to update.